# Thread that returns value when it succeeds or fails?

Tags: python

I have a function that opens up a process and sends commands, gets results and based on this runs more commands. At any stage it could fail and return or at the end it prints out a success statement. Now this all happens on the main thread so my program is stalled while this happens (takes about 6 minutes). How do you change this code to be run in the background but at the end print out the one line that I need?

Here is a snippet:

```
def ran_network_listen(access_point_id):
    # "read hnb" command, check if location has IP set.
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_rancli, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc_stdout  = proc.communicate(ran_opt_read_hnb)[0]

    parse = proc_stdout.split('\n')
    list_of_aps = ""
    for item in parse:
        if  access_point_id in item:
            if "n/c" in item:
                print "AP has no ip."
                #return
            else:    
                print item
        list_of_aps += item      

    if not access_point_id in list_of_aps:
        print "AP not registered"
        return
    //etc
```

For a start I just tried this:

```
  t = Thread(target=ran_network_listen, args=(args.ap_id,))
  t.start()
```

However than just runs in the foreground.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by background/foreground. The way you're doing it is correct. Threads are running in parallel (there is no such thing as background/foreground relation). If you just want one print, then remove all other.

Comment: When I run my program with or without this threading code it does exactly the same thing, I can see all the commands on the screen, I cant enter other commands into my prompt etc. I dont want to be able to see all this happening, I just want the result at the end.

Comment: Then remove all the `print` statements that you don't need.

Comment: If I remove all the print statements I just get a blank terminal that I can't enter commands into until the thread is complete. I dont get a prompt etc. ie, it's acting like it was before I had this thread code, no difference? If it was running in the background would the prints still be shown?

Comment: Basically even without prints, my terminal is still stuck for 6 minutes without me being able to enter any commands.

Comment: That's probably because your input code is in the same thread, you have to move it outside of that thread. Or are you saying that you want to fire entire script in the OS background?

Comment: I'm not so sure on my terminology sorry. I want the same functionality as you get from something like `firefox &` in a terminal. I am on a switch, I enter this command and I want it to do everything in the background. Meanwhile I am still able to enter commands into the switch. When the thread ends I should get a print to my main thread saying so.

Comment: So you probably need something like *screen*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created a background *thread* in your Python process but it seems you want a background *process* in your shell.

Python process won't exit until all non-daemonic threads are complete (it joins them on shutdown).

You could put the whole script into background in the shell:

```
bash$ nohup python your_script.py &>output &
```

Or run it inside [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/).

Python process can be made a [daemon](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/#correct-daemon-behaviour) using [`python-daemon`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) package but daemons are not usually used for one-off tasks.

Comment: Ah i see yes, I was wondering could I just do it in python with a  thread or multiprocess. Gonna look up this stuff and have a go later thanks. I guess I could call a bash command from the switch

Comment: @Paul: I've mentioned `python-daemon` package that allows to put a process into background correctly in Python. But it is probably a massive overkill for your case.

Comment: Thanks, which would be simplest then? Remove the function I want to run in the background from my file into a new script and just using the bash command to call it? Can I display certain information from that in my shell then etc? Will try thanks.

Comment: actually might try start-stop daemon, that looks easy.

Comment: @Paul: the simplest solution is to use a terminal multiplexer such as `screen`, `tmux`.